# UI grid check box selection change in a call back function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, sweetalert

To check/uncheck the check box value, when the sweet alert cancel event is selected.

here in the call back function, not able to reset the check box value.

```
$scope.updateRow = function(row) {
  SweetAlertService.confirm('Are you sure?','', function(isConfirmed) {
    if (isConfirmed) {

    }else{
          if(row.entity.employed == "Y"){
         row.entity.employed = "N";
       }else if(row.entity.employed == "N"){
         row.entity.employed = "Y";
    }
     });
```

Code here . http://plnkr.co/edit/Sd7Uk5yTkhPFnzrsDknp?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes needed to run this are as follows:

1. In `SweetAlert.js` set the timer to some bigger value. Current is 1500, set to timer: 150000.
2. Include `onRegisterApi` in grid definition and after resetting the value of checkbox on click of cancel just refresh the grid using `$scope.gridApi.core.refresh()`

Updated Plunker code: [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j5dJWYbBT3MyisEUOk9l?p=preview)

Hope this  helps!